# sorted function for list not processing strings with numbers correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote some code for a Google python class, which sorts through lists based on the last element in the tuplet or string, and which sorts based on the second to last element in case of ties etc.

```
def better_sort_last(tuples):
    list_1=sorted(tuples, key=len)
    return(sorted(list_1, key=lambda tup:(tup[len(tup)-1],...,[0])))
```

The code works fine for lists with tuplets:

```
[(1, 7), (4, 5), (3, 4, 5), (2,)]-> [(2,), (4, 5), (3, 4, 5), (1, 7)]
```

But incorrectly for lists of strings:
Instead of sorting `['a', 'b', '1a', '2a', '11a', '21a']` into `['a', '1a', '11a', '21a', '2a', 'b']`, it gives `['1a', '11a', '2a', '21a', 'a', 'b']`

Judging from the answer the code seems to read double-digit numbers as a single number, rather than each digit being a seperate element. What can I do to fix this.

Cheers!

Comment: In addition to the answers below, the natsort module can be used too: https://pypi.org/project/natsort/

Answer (score 1):

The sorting actually works fine. When dealing with sorting strings in Python, the sorting is done for char-by-char. The sorting is done lexicographically, meaning the Unicode value of `1` is smaller than `a`, and same for `2` which is also smaller than `a`.
The value of each char is determined by their [ASCII VALUE](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html).

If you still want to reach your desired output, you'll need to tweak your code a bit. Here's an example:

```
def custom_sort_key(s):
    # Split the string into non-digit prefix and digit suffix parts
    non_digit_prefix = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, s))
    digit_suffix = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, s))

    # Convert digit part to integer for proper numeric comparison
    digit_suffix = int(digit_suffix) if digit_suffix else -1  # Use -1 or some flag value for strings without digits

    return non_digit_prefix, digit_suffix


strings = ['a', 'b', '1a', '2a', '11a', '21a']
sorted_strings = sorted(strings, key=custom_sort_key)
print(sorted_strings)
```

This way you first address letters and only then take care of the digit using the `isalpha` and `isdigit` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lambda` doesn't take all the elements of the value in case of a tie, it takes only the first one. To use all the elements you can use reversed value as key

```
return sorted(list_1, key=lambda x: x[::-1])
```